# Leaflet tooltip issue on multiple markers at same location

Tags: leaflet, tooltip, marker

i have two different markers at same location.For the marker at the bottom it has a tooltip while the marker at the top has not. when i hover my mouse on markers the tooltip doesn't show up.

what can i do about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [zIndexOffset](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-zindexoffset) to show the marker with the tooltip on top.

```
L.marker([0,0], {zIndexOffset: 1}).addTo(map).bindTooltip('TEST')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/gaoydfcb/

Comment: yes i knew that  feature but i want to stay it at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

i just bind bottom marker's tooltip to top marker's tooltip and it solved my problem:

```
marker_at_bottom.bindTooltip(...); // that tooltip was not visible
marker_at_top.bindTooltip(marker_at_bottom.getTooltip()); // so i just assigned bottom's tooltip to top one
```